# Osgi swing embedd application

Tags: java, swing, osgi

I'm new to osgi, I'm learning its basis through internet. Yesterday I downloaded some codes from www.eclipsezone.com/files/jsig/code.zip. I can run all applications using apache felix typing java -jar bin/felix.jar . 
But, I tried to embedd felix in the project Explorer  using following code:

```
package org.example.osgi.explorer.internal;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import org.apache.felix.framework.Felix;
import org.apache.felix.framework.util.FelixConstants;
import org.osgi.framework.Bundle;
import org.osgi.framework.Constants;
public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] argv) throws Exception {
        Map<String, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,
            "some.module.i.dont.know; version=1.0.0");

        ExplorerActivator activator = new ExplorerActivator();

        List<Object> list = new LinkedList<>();
        list.add(activator);
        map.put(FelixConstants.SYSTEMBUNDLE_ACTIVATORS_PROP, list);

        Felix f = new Felix(map);

        System.out.println("starting OSGI...");
        f.start();
        String home_dir="file:/G:/code2/JSIG_OSGi/";

        Bundle b = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"projects/Explorer/dist/Explorer.jar");
        Bundle b2 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"projects/PropertiesAction/dist/PropertiesAction.jar");
//            Bundle b3 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"projects/ViewAction/dist/ViewAction.jar");
//            Bundle b4 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"bundles/org.apache.fop_0.20.5.jar");
//            Bundle b5 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"bundles/org.apache.fop_0.93.0.jar");
//            Bundle b6 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"projects/Fop20RenderAction/dist/Fop20RenderAction.jar");
//            Bundle b7 = f.getBundleContext().installBundle(home_dir+"projects/Fop93RenderAction/dist/Fop93RenderAction.jar");

//            String bName = b.getLocation();
//
//            System.out.println("starting bundle " + bName);
            b.start();
             b2.start();



        }
}
```

When I run the main app I go t following error:

```
starting OSGI...
ERROR: Bundle org.apache.felix.framework [0] EventDispatcher: Error during dispatch. (java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.osgi.propertiesaction.PropertiesAction cannot be cast to org.example.osgi.explorer.FileSelectionListener)
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.example.osgi.propertiesaction.PropertiesAction cannot be cast to org.example.osgi.explorer.FileSelectionListener
at org.example.osgi.explorer.internal.FileSelectionService.addingService(FileSelectionService.java:35)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:932)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.customizerAdding(ServiceTracker.java:864)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.trackAdding(AbstractTracked.java:256)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.AbstractTracked.track(AbstractTracked.java:229)
at org.osgi.util.tracker.ServiceTracker$Tracked.serviceChanged(ServiceTracker.java:894)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.invokeServiceListenerCallback(EventDispatcher.java:932)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireEventImmediately(EventDispatcher.java:793)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.EventDispatcher.fireServiceEvent(EventDispatcher.java:543)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.fireServiceEvent(Felix.java:4419)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.registerService(Felix.java:3423)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleContextImpl.registerService(BundleContextImpl.java:346)
at org.example.osgi.propertiesaction.Activator.start(Activator.java:22)
at org.apache.felix.framework.util.SecureAction.startActivator(SecureAction.java:645)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.activateBundle(Felix.java:2146)
at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:2064)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:955)
at org.apache.felix.framework.BundleImpl.start(BundleImpl.java:942)
at org.example.osgi.explorer.internal.Main.main(Main.java:55)
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 16 seconds)
```

Why this exception occurs.How can I solve this issue?

Edit:
Yes it implements!
code:

```
package org.example.osgi.propertiesaction;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.io.File;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JDialog;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import org.example.osgi.explorer.FileSelectionListener;
public class PropertiesAction extends AbstractAction implements FileSelectionListener {

private static final File[] EMPTY = new File[0];

private File[] selection;

public PropertiesAction() {
    super("Properties");
    setEnabled(false);
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
    Frame frame = (Frame) SwingUtilities.getAncestorOfClass(Frame.class, (Component) event.getSource());
    FilePropertiesDialog dialog = new FilePropertiesDialog(selection, frame, true);
    dialog.setVisible(true);
}

public void selectionChanged(File[] selection) {
    this.selection = (selection == null) ? EMPTY : selection;
    setEnabled(selection != null && selection.length > 0);
}

}
```

Edit: Following code has worked:

```
FrameworkFactory ff = new FrameworkFactory ();
Map<String,Object> config = new HashMap<String,Object>();
config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_SYSTEMPACKAGES_EXTRA,"packages needed,more packages needed");   
config.put(Constants.FRAMEWORK_STORAGE_CLEAN, "true");

Framework fwk = ff.newFramework(config);
fwk.start();
BundleContext context = fwk.getBundleContext();

String home_dir="file:/G:/code2/JSIG_OSGi/";
Bundle bundle = context.installBundle(home_dir+"projects/Explorer/dist/Explorer.jar");
bundle.start();
Bundle bundle2 = context.installBundle(home_dir+
"projects/PropertiesAction/dist/PropertiesAction.jar");
 bundle2.start();

//ExplorerActivator.isopened will be false if frame disposed.
if(ExplorerActivator.isopened) {

 bundle.stop();
 bundle2.stop();
 bundle.uninstall();
 bundle2.uninstall();
 fwk.stop();
 fwk.waitForStop(1000);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer is that you are casting an instance of `PropertiesAction` to the interface `org.example.osgi.explorer.FileSelectionListener`, but it doesn't actually implement that interface.

If you believe it *does* implement that interface then you need to provide more information.

Comment: According to the exception, you are right. But why this exception happens while embedding? I can run this bundle typing java -jar bin/felix.jar.